# Issue Related to GridView in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have gridview binded from database..

I have following code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
```

Now, I have `checkBox` and `drop-down` inside the gridView, When user selects some rows from checkboxes and clicks on `Update Button`, `Page_Load` event fires and calls `BindGrid();` method and selected rows should get hidden.

How can I retain checkbox values after the page load event.

I don't want to use `IsPostBack` property in Page load because I have used Paging.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only `DataBind` the GridView `if(!Page.IsPostback)`. Otherwise no events are triggered and ViewState values(like SelectedIndex etc.) are overwritten from the `DataSource` values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   BindGrid();
}
```

You also should call `BindGrid` from following event-handlers:

- `PageIndexChanging`
- `SelectedIndexChanged`
- `Sorting`

Answer (score 2):

Make use of ISpostback..

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   BindGrid();
}
```

call bindgrid from the pagaing event

```
function of paging event
{
 BindGrid();
}
```